# Applying GLM like "perspective" and "lookat" calculations results in my shape disappearing

Tags: opengl, matrix, transformation, projection, pyglet

I'm new to OpenGL and am working my way through translating the C++ OpenGL tutorials at http://open.gl/ to Python and Pyglet (https://github.com/01AutoMonkey/open.gl-tutorials-to-pyglet) and am currently at the second example in the "Transformation" section (http://open.gl/transformations).

It's done, except I just get a black screen instead of an image moving in a particular way (two triangles making up a rectangle are suppose to rotate and the camera is suppose to tilt a little). The problem seems to stem from matrix calculations, more specifically the applying of "perspective" and "lookat" to gain a "projection". If I remove those two from my vertex shader calculations it works, I get a rotating image, but without the tilting of the camera which the two matrixes were suppose to deliver.

I've compared my code with the C++ code and I don't see any discrepancies and I fail to see where the problem could lie.

How I'm translating the code:

- C++ to Python and ctypes
- SFML to Pyglet
- GLEW to pyglet.gl
- SOIL to pyglet.image
- GLM to [pyeuclid](https://code.google.com/p/pyeuclid/) <-- note that pyeuclid is what I'm using to calculate the matrices

Could it be I'm suppose to send the matrices in some other form then a flat list? Also maybe the code is working but I'm doing something wrong or pyglet works differently and therefore the image is displayed outside the screen?

The C++ code:

```
// Set up projection
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f),
    glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
);
GLint uniView = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniView, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(45.0f, 800.0f / 600.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f);
GLint uniProj = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "proj");
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniProj, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj));
```

My Python, Pyglet code equivilant:

```
# Set up projection
eye = Vector3(1.2, 1.2, 1.2)
at = Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
up = Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
view = Matrix4.new_look_at(eye, at, up)
view = view[:]
view_ctype = (GLfloat * len(view))(*view)
uniView = glGetUniformLocation(shader.handle, "view")
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniView, 1, GL_FALSE, view_ctype)

proj = Matrix4.new_perspective(45.0, 800.0 / 600.0, 1.0, 10.0)
proj = proj[:]
proj_ctype = (GLfloat * len(proj))(*proj)
uniProj = glGetUniformLocation(shader.handle, "proj")
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniProj, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_ctype)
```

The full script:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from shader import Shader
from ctypes import pointer, sizeof
import math
import time
from euclid import *


window = pyglet.window.Window(800, 600, "OpenGL")
window.set_location(100, 100)


# Shaders (Vertex and Fragment shaders)
vertex = """
#version 150

in vec2 position;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec2 Texcoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

void main() {
    Texcoord = texcoord;
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
"""
fragment = """
#version 150 core

in vec2 Texcoord;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D texKitten;
uniform sampler2D texPuppy;

void main() {
   outColor = mix(texture(texKitten, Texcoord), texture(texPuppy, Texcoord), 0.5);
}
"""
## Compiling shaders and combining them into a program 
shader = Shader(vertex, fragment)
shader.bind() #glUseProgram


# Vertex Input
## Vertex Array Objects
vao = GLuint()
glGenVertexArrays(1, pointer(vao))
glBindVertexArray(vao)

## Vertex Buffer Object
vbo = GLuint()
glGenBuffers(1, pointer(vbo)) # Generate 1 buffer

#           Position    Texcoords
vertices = [-0.5,  0.5, 0.0, 1.0,
             0.5,  0.5, 1.0, 1.0,
             0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 0.0,
            -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0]

## Convert the verteces array to a GLfloat array, usable by glBufferData
vertices_gl = (GLfloat * len(vertices))(*vertices)

## Upload data to GPU
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices_gl), vertices_gl, GL_STATIC_DRAW)


# Element array
ebo = GLuint()
glGenBuffers(1, pointer(ebo))

elements = [0, 1, 2,
            2, 3, 0]
elements_gl = (GLuint * len(elements))(*elements)

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements_gl), elements_gl, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


# Making the link between vertex data and attributes
## shader.handle holds the value of glCreateProgram()
posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shader.handle, "position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shader.handle, "texcoord");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));


# Load textures
textures = [0] * 2
textures_ctype = (GLuint * len(textures))(*textures)
glGenTextures(2, textures_ctype);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures_ctype[0]);

image = pyglet.image.load("sample.png")
width, height = image.width, image.height
image = image.get_data('RGB', width * 3)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.handle, "texKitten"), 0);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures_ctype[1]);

image = pyglet.image.load("sample2.png")
width, height = image.width, image.height
image = image.get_data('RGB', width * 3)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.handle, "texPuppy"), 1);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

uniModel = glGetUniformLocation(shader.handle, "model");

# Set up projection
eye = Vector3(1.2, 1.2, 1.2)
at = Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
up = Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
view = Matrix4.new_look_at(eye, at, up)
view = view[:]
view_ctype = (GLfloat * len(view))(*view)
uniView = glGetUniformLocation(shader.handle, "view")
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniView, 1, GL_FALSE, view_ctype)

proj = Matrix4.new_perspective(45.0, 800.0 / 600.0, 1.0, 10.0)
proj = proj[:]
proj_ctype = (GLfloat * len(proj))(*proj)
uniProj = glGetUniformLocation(shader.handle, "proj")
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniProj, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_ctype)


# Set clear color
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)


@window.event
def on_draw():
    # Clear the screen to black
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    # Calculate transformation
    model = Quaternion.new_rotate_axis(time.clock() * math.pi, Vector3(0, 0, 1))
    model = model.get_matrix()[:]
    model_ctype = (GLfloat * len(model))(*model)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniModel, 1, GL_FALSE, model_ctype);

    # Draw a rectangle from the 2 triangles using 6 indices
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    pass

@window.event
def on_key_release(symbol, modifiers):
    pass

def update(dt):
    pass
pyglet.clock.schedule(update)


pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Okay I've found one bug, 45.0 in Matrix4.new_perspective(45.0, 800.0 / 600.0, 1.0, 10.0) is defined in degrees while it should be in radians, fixing this still gives me a black screen but it's a start: Matrix4.new_perspective(math.radians(45.0), 800.0 / 600.0, 1.0, 10.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL expects matrices to be provided in column-major order.  GLM uses the same convention, however many matrix math libraries not designed for use with OpenGL use row-major order.

My python is rusty, but a cursory inspection of the source for pyeuclid seems to confirm that they are using row-major order.

Therefore, you need to convert from row-major to column major order before passing any matrices to functions like `glUniformMatrix4fv`.  Luckily, this is a simple matter; it's just the transpose of the matrix!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input! But this doesn't seem to be the problem, doing [:] on a matrix does result in a list with a column major order, but just in case I did a transpose but still nothing.

Comment: I've compared the matrix output with the output of a javascript equivilant, the perspective matrix matches but not the lookat matrix! I'm going to see if I can't get the lookat matrix to match.

Comment: Manually entering the lookat matrix gives me the correct results! I notice the lookat method isn't documented in pyeuclid, maybe it's incomplete? I'm going to make sure I'm using it right and maybe try fixing it if it's incomplete.

Comment: From what I understand, `[:]` merely copies the list (though admittedly, I've only played around with python in passing a few times).  How exactly is this supposed to invoke the transpose member function?  Clearly, matrix coefficients are stored in the list in row-major order; see `__slots__ = list('abcefgijk')`

Comment: After taking a look at `new_look_at`, it seems it does have a bug.  The LookAt transform can be thought of as the combination of a translation and a basis-change.  The translation effectively moves the origin to the `eye`, and therefore, conceptually it occurs before the basis-change, since `eye` is defined in world-space, not view-space.  Therefore, the last line in `new_look_at` should be `m.d, m.h, m.l = -x.dot(eye), -y.dot(eye), -z.dot(eye)`

Comment: And changing `m.l` to `m.o` so the `-z.dot(eye)` enters the right location (at least in my case and perhaps all cases):

`m.d, m.h, m.o = -x.dot(eye), -y.dot(eye), -z.dot(eye)`

And now it works!

Comment: One weirdness though, I have to transpose the lookat matrix results, but not any of the other matrix results, so perhaps transpose should also be included in the pyeuclid lookat code (`m.transpose()`)

Comment: No, `d`, `h`, and `l` are the correct members.  The bottom row of homogenous transformation matrices is almost always `[0, 0, 0, 1]`.  (Projection matrices are the primary exception to this).  You're probably still forgetting a `transpose()` somewhere.

Comment: Okay, new solution that works is to put a `m.transpose()` right before `m.d, m.h, m.l = -x.dot(eye), -y.dot(eye), -z.dot(eye)`, and then everything is in place.

Comment: Ah, yes, the `new_rotate_triple_axis` is a bit wonky as well.  I assumed that was just a poorly named function for generating a 3x3 basis-change matrix, but you do need the transpose for that to work.  Also, if you're not using transpose on your projection matrix before uploading it, you should be.  The reason it works without it is that the `l` and `o` members (the only nonzero members swapped by transpose) are `-20/9` and `-1` for your choice of `zNear` and `zFar`.  Other choices of clipping planes may not generate such similar coefficients.